# Having problems with dropped hard disk

Tags: hard-drive

I was playing Xbox and my 3TB Seagate external hard drive fell and hit the floor. I plugged it back into the Xbox and now it wont detect my games from the hard drive. is there a way to fix this. The hard drive turns on and acts normal but it wont move my games over.

Comment: I would take it to a local recovery agency for an assessment (free or low cost). Like the heads contacted the disk surface because of the jolt.

Comment: I there anything else on it, try connecting it to a PC and see how or if it works.

Comment: First thing to do is make an image of the HDD. Then you can try to recover files from the HDD or the image. Any further use of the HDD only makes recovery less likely.

Comment: Every single game on the HDD can be downloaded again.  Data recovery will be tough since it’s from an Xbox.  Connecting it to a pc is a waste of time

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware, that an HDD (Hard drive disk) consists of mechanical parts moving to write & read the data on the disks. If you drop an HDD it can happen that you won't have any real option other to get it to a data recovery service which can cost up to many hundreds or thousands of dollars/euros to get the undamaged data.

The question is if it's cheaper in your case to buy a new HDD and the games which you don't have any longer available (I'm not the console type of player)